# How can I find out if these two polygons intersect? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, leaflet, geospatial, polygon

I have two polygons in below format. They're effectively an array of lat-long coordinates (in that order):

```
number[][] | [] | [number, number] | number[]
```

How can I determine if they intersect? I've tried converting the polygons to Leaflet `Polygon`s and using `intersect` from `turf` but I get a `TS2322` error.

Example Polygons:

```
Polygon 1: [[50, -0.2],[52, -0.3],[51, -0.4],[50, 0],[51, -0.8]]

Polygon 2: [[51, -0.1],[51, -0.2],[51, -0.4],[53, 0.1],[52, -0.3]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Convert them to [GeoJSON format](https://geojson.org/),*then* run the TurfJS function.

Comment: Okay, how do I convert them to GeoJSON format?

Comment: Start by a) reading the GeoJSON standard and b) editing your question to add a couple examples of your polygons (so that your question resembles a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and to see the [axis order](https://macwright.org/lonlat/))